How to rename Wix MSI file to include version in VS2022 Post build event
I am currently working on a Wix Setup Project for a .Net 8 desktop application.
I am using VS 2022 and running the Heatwave extension and Wix 5.x.
I want to somehow rename the built msi file to include version.
Current name is
TankRadar.ServiceTool.Setup.msi and would like the name to be TankRadar.ServiceTool.Setup_[Version].msi eg. TankRadar.ServiceTool.Setup_1.2.0.0.msi

I have tried to do this in the post build event, but as this is a Wix project the version is not accessible the same way as in normal c# projects.
What I have tried so far is this in the post build event:
rename "$(TargetDir)\en-US\$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetName)_$(ProductVersion).msi"

But the $(ProductVersion) seems to be empty, I have also tried a whole list of other variable names but none seem to work.

You can set the OutputName property in your wixproj file (works for msi and bundle).
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputName>$(TargetName)_$(ProductVersion)</OutputName>
</PropertyGroup>

Note that the extension is not specified in OutputName.

This does not work in my project, I have solved it in my buildpipeline with a powershell script.
